Does AWS DMS has a 30 character limit on the length of Table and Column name to be replicated?
I am a data modeler and while modeling my tables in Postgres 14.7, I was told that the table and column names cannot exceed 30 characters, since AWS DMS replication will only allow maximum 30 characters for table and column name (eventhough the database will let more than 64 characters)
Is this correct? I understand that the underlying data might have length limits but does object names have limit in DMS?
If yes, is this limitation on certain DMS version? (I see some of ours are DMS 3.5 , but could have older ones as well for other applications). Please help clarify if this is specific to any DMS version?
Thanks
Sunil

Ask the one who told you this. He or she can explain it to you and show you the documentation that shows the details about this.
